# How can I bring water to 90 degrees C?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, water

For my coffee I need the water to be 90 degrees Celsuis. Boiling water, however, is 100 degrees. How can I make it 90 degrees?

Do I just measure the temperature of the water from my tap, and if it's 10 degrees and I have boiled 6 dl of 100 degree water then I add x such that

$$10x+100 \cdot 6=(x+6)90$$

Or how should I go about it? In the equation above I assumed linearity.

Comment: That should work.  But if you've got a thermometer, you could cheat.  Just boil up some water, then keep adding cold water until the temperature drops to 90C.